# How can I validate a date in different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I got a regular expression to valid a date which is as follows

`^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$`

But this will valid if I enter date as follows `20/03/2012` .. With the same I would like to add different validation which can work together for the following

`20032012 (ddmmyyyy)` `03202012(mmddyyyy)`

Can some one help me

Comment: 1. Wrong tool for the job.  Use custom validation logic or a Compare/RangeValidator. 2. You can't parse *both* mm/dd and dd/mm, otherwise how would you determine whether 05/04 was May 4th or April 5th?

Comment: use custom validator and use different regex to validate date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) - there is an overload that takes an array of format strings, so you can supply all of the possible formats.

From MSDN - [DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx):

```
string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                   "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};
string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                        "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                        "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00"}; 
DateTime dateValue;

foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
{
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
      Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
   else
      Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:05 PM.
//       Converted '5/1/2009 6:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 PM.
//       Converted '05/01/2009 06:32:00' to 5/1/2009 6:32:00 AM.
```

Comment: How can you parse both mm/dd and dd/mm because, for example, 05/04 would be ambiguous?

Comment: YOu can not. THAT ASIMPLE. 05/04 can not be uutomatically parsed WITHOUT CONTEXT. Basically oyu must know whether the locale is english or geran, for example. SImple point - negotiate with user (if that is asp.net) using standard browser mechnaisms. If that is a file, then someone did a crap job specifying the format.

Comment: Yes, but the answer still is: Not possible, sorry. MUST clarify formats for that.

Comment: ;)Thus: -1 for creating a problem because this just does not work withut knowing the local, and in this case it is a matter of futility as locale relevant parsing is already implemented.

Comment: @TomTom - You put no effort into your answer.  You just said it was not possible except it is.  It requires user invention and/or a flag to indicate the format but it is possible.  The data has to come from some place.  More information would be required.  A "not possible" statement is just silly.